# Entity Framework - What if I want my stored procedure return nothing at all

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am using Entity framework with stored procedures, and its all working fine.

I encountered a strange problem when I created an SP in SQL Server which is only inserting single row. Normally I used to return the current scope identity when an SP is inserting a record. But what if I deliberately do not want to return anything from SP. In this case Entity Framework is not generating the SP method as it has generated for all other SPs.

Although I can simply return an int value just to satisfy EF, but I am curious to know the reason why it is not creating a function for this particular case.

I used EF by Item Template Entity Data Model(.edmx file)

Comment: This is way to unclear to consider answering.

Comment: So SP should always have to return something?

Comment: @M_Idrees It does not need to return something

Comment: Yes. this is what I was expecting. But somehow it is not creating a function/call for that SP in the model generated.